# Xamarin Shell Right to left FlowDirection not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

I'm developing a new cross-platform application with Xamarin 4.0 and I want change layouts to right to left direction.

I want shell items and flyout menu in right of screen. I tried this code in Shell tag. But it didn't work.

```
FlowDirection = "RightToLeft"
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately**, it should be the limit of Shell Flyout .

**FlowDirection**:Just can modify the direction of subview's content, not the parent layout of it.

After testing in official sample [Xamarin.Forms - Xaminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) , setting `FlowDirection = "RightToLeft"` can not changing Flyout from left of screen to right of screen.

[image]

Note: If have other solutions to solve the direction of parent layout, will update here.

Answer (score 2):

in main activity inside OnCreate method: Make it look like that

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Rtl;

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```